# SQS: AWS.SimpleQueueService.UnsupportedOperation: Message attribute list values in SendMessage operation are not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-js

I am using aws-sdk-js to send message to a standard queue in AWS. Below is the payload,

```
{
  MessageBody: 'UUID',
  QueueUrl: 'https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<account>/<queue-name>',
  DelaySeconds: 0,
  MessageAttributes: {
    attribute1: {
      StringValue: 'UUID',
      StringListValues: [],
      BinaryListValues: [],
      DataType: 'String'
    },
    attribute2: {
      StringValue: 'SQS',
      StringListValues: [],
      BinaryListValues: [],
      DataType: 'String'
    },
    attribute3: {
      StringValue: 'UUID',
      StringListValues: [],
      BinaryListValues: [],
      DataType: 'String'
    }
  }
}
```

Code Snippet,

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const sqs = new AWS.SQS();
const params = { /* the above object */ }
sqs.sendMessage(params).promise();
```

But I am getting this error,

```
AWS.SimpleQueueService.UnsupportedOperation: Message attribute list values in SendMessage operation are not supported.
```

What is the error? do I need to stringify the payload?

Answer (score 1):

You have not given the code to generate the message so hard to tell how the unsupported values got in the payload.

But, there is no 'list' dataType for message attrribute values . [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-metadata.html#message-attribute-data-types). The only supported dataTypes are

- String
- Number
- Binary
- Custom (uses one of the above to create a custom field e.g. Number.EmployeeId)

[java example from aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-java-send-message-with-attributes.html)

In your message payload, below two fields values are list dataTypes

```
  StringListValues: [],
  BinaryListValues: [],
```

You should remove them.